# Formatar string para (dd/mm)

Tags: javascript, data

Recebo uma string de 4 dígitos (numeros), e preciso quebrá-la no meio, e colocar uma “/”, para formatar no tipo (dd/mm)

```
<input [(ngModel)]="contato.birth" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="DIA/MÊS" mask="99/99" />
```

e ao exibir esse valor, preciso que ele seja formatado em JavaScript, como (dd / mm) como "06/08", por exemplo. Tentei usar as funções split e join, mas não tive muito sucesso, tentei isso:

```
formatBirthday(date) {
    let result = date.split('-').join('/');

    return result
}
```

```
<p *ngIf="business.cliente.birth">
  <b class="b-b">Aniversário: </b>
  {{formatBirthday(business.cliente.birth)}}
</p>
```

alguém saberia alguma maneira para formatar apenas dd / mm?

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara!

Comment: Editei a pergunta, creio que melhorou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Também é possível usar expressões regulares para fazer isso. Veja:

```
/^(\d{2})(\d{2})$/
```

Na expressão acima, criamos dois [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Cada um deles procurará por sequência de dois dígitos. Para isso, utilizamos o [atalho para a classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) de números (`[0-9]`) `\d` junto do quantificador `{2}`.

Então, podes fazer assim:

```js
const re = /^(\d{2})(\d{2})$/;
const str = '0608';

const [, day, month] = str.match(re);

const dateStr = `${day}/${month}`;

console.log(dateStr);
```

O método [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) foi utilizado. Ele retornará um *array* com os grupos de captura encontrados a partir do índice 1. Assim, utilizamos a [desestruturação de *arrays*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) para obtê-los.

Comment: Ótima resposta, me ajudou com o problema, obrigado ;) !!!

Answer (score 2):

Pode utilizar o método [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) para isso de uma maneira bem simples, lembrando que isso dá para ser feito de várias formas, como o uso de uma **regex** por exemplo:

```js
let date = '0608';

console.log(`${date.slice(0,2)}/${date.slice(2,4)}`)
```

Comment: Essa maneira também resolveu o problema, obrigado ;) !!!